# Pass variable from parent view to child view through uinavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, modalviewcontroller

Sorry if this seems like a simple question, but every time I search on google for this subject all I can find is how to pass data from a child view to a parent view, not vice versa.

Basically, I am presenting a modal view, which is in its own UINavigation controller.  The modal view needs to know if it is allowed to be 'edited' by the user or not - so I thought the most simple way to do this would be to set a BOOL on the child view (isEdit) to TRUE (this would get set depending on the segue that is occurring)  However because this modal view is being presented from a UINavigation controller - I cannot access it from the -(void)prepareForSegue function and set the BOOL directly.  I have tried subclassing the UINav controller, and including a BOOL in it that can be set, then checked back in the child view, but I cannot seem to access the controller from the child view - I would include my code, but I am sure there must be a more simple way of accomplishing this task!

Is anyone able to suggest a more economical way of passing this boolean 'through' the UINavigationController to the child view?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your segue invokes a navigation controller, you can set properties on the root view controller from `-prepareForSegue`, like so

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegueId"]) {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        MyViewController *childController = (MyViewController *)navController.childViewControllers.lastObject;
        childController.isEditable = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is if you're using storyboards, or you're calling the segue programatically. If not, you can just set the property when you init the child view controller, as per Joel's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

When you alloc/init the modal view controller just set the property then (say your modal view controller is called ProfileVC):

```
ProfileVC *vc = [[ProfileVC alloc] init];
vc.isEdit = YES;
[vc.navigationController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

just make sure in your ProfileVC.h you have a property called isEdit:

```
@interface ProfileVC : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isEdit;
@end
```

Comment: The OP said the nav controller itself is modal. That is, doing it this way, you'd set the property before initialising the navController with the childVC using `–initWithRootViewController:`.